# solving ODE contain matrix

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-matrices

I am currently researching the specific image generation problem in this paper 'Score_Based Generative modeling through stochastic differential equation' At the end of page 14, the authors are using equation (5.51) in Sarkka & Solin (2019) to govern the evolution of the variance. However, the equation provided in the paper (1) seems slightly different from the equation (2) in Sarkka & Solin (2019) and since I'm relatively new to SDE, I don't understand why there's this discrepancy.

The bolded characters are the matrices

Equation in paper:

> $\frac{\mathrm{d} \boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{\mathrm{VP}}(t)}{\mathrm{d} t}=\beta(t)\left(\mathbf{I}-\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{\mathrm{VP}}(t)\right) (1)$

Equation in  Sarkka & Solin (2019):

> $\begin{aligned}
> \frac{\mathrm{d} \mathbf{P}}{\mathrm{d} t} =  \mathrm{E}\left[\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}, t)(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{m})^{\top}\right]+\mathrm{E}\left[(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{m}) \mathbf{f}^{\top}(\mathbf{x}, t)\right]  +\mathrm{E}\left[\mathbf{L}(\mathbf{x}, t) \mathbf{Q} \mathbf{L}^{\top}(\mathbf{x}, t)\right],
> \end{aligned} (2)$

The solution to equation (1) is published in the paper:

> $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{\mathrm{VP}}(t)=\mathbf{I}+e^{\int_0^t-\beta(s) \mathrm{d} s}\left(\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{\mathrm{VP}}(0)-\mathbf{I}\right) (3) $

Additionally, I've attempted to solve equation (1), but my result doesn't match the equation (3) presented in the paper:

> $\begin{gathered}
> e^{\int \beta(s) d s} \frac{d \Sigma_{V P}(t)}{d t}+e^{\int \beta(s) d s} \beta(t) \Sigma_{V P}(t)=e^{\int \beta(s) d s} \beta(t) . I \\
> d\left(e^{\int \beta(s) d s} \Sigma_{V P}(t)\right)=e^{\int \beta(s) d s} \beta(t) . I \\
> \int_0^t d\left(e^{\int \beta(s) d s} \Sigma_{V P}(t)\right)=\int_0^t e^{\int \beta(s) d s} \beta(\tau) \cdot I d \tau \\
> \Sigma_{V P}(t)-\Sigma_{V P}(0)=e^{-\int \beta(s) d s}\left(\int_0^t e^{\int \beta(s) d s} \beta(\tau) \cdot I d \tau\right) \\
> \Sigma_{V P}(t)=e^{-\int \beta(s) d s}\left(\int_0^t e^{\int \beta(s) d s} \beta(\tau) \cdot I d \tau\right)+\Sigma_{V P}(0)
> \end{gathered}$

I really need assistance because I am currently conducting this research without any guidance or support from anyone.

Answer (score 0):

You are close, but have a few mistakes.

$$\begin{gathered}
e^{\int_{\color{red}{0}}^{\color{red}{t}} \beta(s) d s} \frac{d \Sigma_{V P}(t)}{d t}+e^{\int_{\color{red}{0}}^{\color{red}{t}} \beta(s) d s} \beta(t) \Sigma_{V P}(t)=e^{\int_{\color{red}{0}}^{\color{red}{t}} \beta(s) d s} \beta(t) \cdot I \\
d\left(e^{\int_{\color{red}{0}}^{\color{red}{t}} \beta(s) d s} \Sigma_{V P}(t)\right)\color{red}{/dt} =e^{\int_{\color{red}{0}}^{\color{red}{t}} \beta(s) d s} \beta(t) \cdot I \\
\int_0^t d\left(e^{\int_{\color{red}{0}}^{\color{red}{\tau}} \beta(s) d s} \Sigma_{V P}(\color{red}{\tau})\right)=\int_0^t e^{\int_{\color{red}{0}}^{\color{red}{\tau}} \beta(s) d s} \beta(\tau) \cdot I d \tau \\
\color{red}{e^{\int_0^\tau \beta(s) d s} \Sigma_{V P}(\tau) \left. \right|_{\tau=0}^t = \int_0^t \frac{d \left(e^{\int_0^\tau \beta(s) d s}\right)}{d \tau} \cdot I d \tau} \\
\color{red}{e^{\int_0^t \beta(s) d s} \Sigma_{V P}(t) - \Sigma_{V P}(0) = e^{\int_0^\tau \beta(s) d s} \left. \right|_{\tau=0}^t \cdot I} 
\end{gathered}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance, do you know the reason for the difference between the two equations (1) (2) above?

Comment: @DucToan you need to give more context to answer this question. They seem to be unrelated unless $\Sigma_{VP}$ has another definition. You need to mention that in your question.

Comment: thank you, Please give me some time to delve deeper, and I will get back to you later.